# Text is blurry over Visual Effects

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

**Background** : I am stacking a couple buttons and a label within a view over an image with some visual effect views for blurring.

**Conundrum** : The text in the buttons and in the label are pixelated while other text is crisp and sharp. It's almost as if the label and buttons have been converted into a badly rendered image.

**DoneDid** :

- Put the buttons and label in it's own view.
- Put the view with label and buttons outside of the Visual Effects view stack.
- Played with the font, scale, various other settings.
- Set the background of the "Inventory Details Bar" to a solid color to check for potential FX leaking up to the overlying view.
- Looked all over for "blurry text over visual effect view" and several variations of the sort.  Nothing that quite matches my current experience.

As always, this community is awesome and I appreciate any ideas that might break through this visual odditiy.

---

***Inventory Type label is the thing we are looking at***
[image: Inventory Type label is the thing we are looking at]

---

***Label details (tried several fonts, not just Arial)***

[image: Label details (tried several fonts, not just Arial)]

---

***Blurry "Inventory Type" label***
[image: Blurry "Inventory Type" label]

Comment: Is your visual effect applied to the whole `Inventory details bar` view?

Comment: The bar was set outside of the visual effects view, however, I had applied a different level of effect to the parent view that rasterized everything in the view.  When I set that to false, it cleared up the issue.
Thanks for following up on my question though!

Answer (score 4):

3 hours researching, 
post for help... 
Found the issue a moment later.

Ok, so the view that contains the image stack with blurring effects, including the label and the background images, has a shadow that I throw over the scrolling cells below it.

In looking for a solution to dealing with the layer shadow,  someone had mentioned  rasterizing the whole view to make it more efficient.  Which means.... it turns the whole view and its contents into an image of sorts to lower processing resources.

It was...
(detailedImageView being the name of the parent UIView)

```
detailedImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

I changed it to "False" which is the default for this parameter and BAM... sharp and crisp text.

I hope this helps someone.
[image]

Comment: You saved me hours!  Thank you for sharing this!